# ¿Cómo acceder a datos guardados en un SharedPreference desde distintas Activities en Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para Android usando Kotlin. Esta aplicación debe poder guardar datos (en mi caso, un JSON). Lo estoy guardando mediante un SharedPreference, y asigno a una variable el valor del JSON guardado usando la llave "Massa_Mare". Si no hay nada guardado, ejecuto la función defaultValues(pref), la cuál me guarda unos valores que yo he asignado previamente y devuelve su respectivo JSON.

Esto funciona correctamente, pero el problema reside en que sólo puedo acceder a estos valores desde la misma Activity. Si me voy a otra Activity e intento acceder a esos valores, no puedo (de hecho, me ha guardado dos valores distintos).

A continuación os envío el código que uso en las dos Activities para acceder a los mismos valores:

MassaMare.kt

```
val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
println("Se guardará en preferencias si no existe Massa_Mare: " + defaultValues(pref))
// Se guardará en preferencias si no existe Massa_Mare: {"pa":500,"percAigua":80,"percFarinaMassaMare":50,"percMassaMare":20,"percPerdua":17,"percSal":2}
val savedData = pref.getString("Massa_Mare", defaultValues(pref))

private fun defaultValues(pref: SharedPreferences): String {
    val myData = MassaMareData(500, 80, 2, 20, 17, 50)
    val json = Gson().toJson(myData)
    val editor = pref.edit()
    editor.putString("Massa_Mare", json)
    editor.apply()
    return json
}
```

Preferment.kt

```
val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
println("Se guardará en preferencias si no existe Massa_Mare: " + defaultValues(pref))
// Se guardará en preferencias si no existe Massa_Mare: {"pa":200,"percAigua":80,"percFarinaMassaMare":50,"percMassaMare":20,"percPerdua":17,"percSal":2}
val savedData = pref.getString("Massa_Mare", defaultValues(pref))

private fun defaultValues(pref: SharedPreferences): String {
        val myData = MassaMareData(200, 80, 2, 20, 17, 50)
        val json = Gson().toJson(myData)
        val editor = pref.edit()
        editor.putString("Massa_Mare", json)
        editor.apply()
        return json
}
```

Como pueden ver en el código, la única diferencia entre ambos fragmentos es el valor por defecto, que cambié a propósito para comprobar si guardaba bien y si podía acceder desde distintas Activities. Pero cada Activity me enseña un valor diferente.

Por desgracia, necesito acceder a esos datos (y editarlos) desde distintas Activities. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Llevo un buen rato buscando y no consigo solucionarlo. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

**Para acceder a los datos guardados desde distintas activities en tu proyecto siempre debes usar el mismo nombre del archivo donde guardas las preferencias**, en este caso sería "Data" :

```
val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Si estas teniendo problemas para leer los datos desde otra Actividad debes asegurar que el valor que tratas de guardar en verdad tiene un valor, puedes imprimirlo para verificar:

```
...
println("se guardará en preferencias: " + defaultValues(pref))
val savedData = pref.getString("Massa_Mare", defaultValues(pref))
editor.apply()
...
```

---

Lo correcto es que tu funcion para guardar los datos, solo realice esta función, no es necesario que retorne ningún valor:

```
  private fun saveValues(pref: SharedPreferences) {
      val myData = MassaMareData(200, 80, 2, 20, 17, 50)
      val json = Gson().toJson(myData)
      val editor = pref.edit()
      editor.putString("Massa_Mare", json)
      editor.apply()
    }
```

Para guardar el valor simplemente llama de esta forma la función:

```
 val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
 saveValues(pref)
```

Si deseas obtener el valor guardado, usa el nombre del archivo y la llave que deseas obtener su valor:

```
  val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
  val savedData = pref.getString("Massa_Mare", "")
  println("Obtiene valor guardado: " + savedData )
```

Comment: Saludos @Elenasys, muchas gracias por responder. He añadido más información en la pregunta (he añadido el código usado en las dos Activities y he puesto en comentarios el resultado de los println que me dijiste). Ambos SharedPreferences usan el mismo nombre de archivo ("Data"), y he imprimido los valores por defecto. Ambos tienen valor. ¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Me parece que la confusión se debe a que la función para guardar obtienes un valor, solo deberías guardar el valor y no es necesario retornar ningún valor, si deseas obtener el valor guardado simplemente realiza esto mediante :   val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)
  val savedData = pref.getString("Massa_Mare", "") revisa mi actualización.

Comment: Saludos @Elenasys, gracias otra vez por responder. Creo que no expliqué bien el procedimiento que uso (no sé si es correcto o no). Yo ejecuto el pref.getString para recibir el JSON guardado. Si hay algo guardado, lo asigno a la variable savedData. Si no, ejecuto la función defaultValues, que guarda el JSON y, como la ejecuto en el getString, también me devuelve el JSON que será automáticamente asignado a la variable savedData. De esta forma, tanto si hay datos guardados como si no, el getString me devuelve datos válidos.

Comment: El problema sigue residiendo en que, usando el getSharedPreferences, estoy recibiendo distintos valores entre distintas activities.

Comment: Asegura que el valor de "pref" lo obtienes siempre de esa manera:  val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: Así es, @Elenasys. Lo recibo mediante `val pref = getSharedPreferences("Data", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE)` en ambas Activities.